# invalid characters in string - regular expression

Tags: regex, mongodb

I am storing filename in my database and when a international language is used, it stores something like below as my filename.

```
 å¹³ç´ ããèª ã«ãä¸è©±ã«ãªã£ã¦ããã¾ã.docx
```

please could someone give me a regular expression which will identify such invalid characters?

The below characters are acceptable :

```
a-z, 0-9 , () <> [] {}  %^&*$#@~"';?:! etc.
```

are all acceptable. Just not the ones above which cannot be seen on the keyboard.

Thanks .

Comment: you really want to allow chars like `@#` etc. as _filenames_ ?

Comment: Make a character class surrounded by `^` and `$` (beginning/end of string), so `^[a-zA-Z0-9.()\[\]{}!@#$%^&*]+$`.  Put anything you want in the character class and [test it here](http://regex101.com/r/vQ5pD5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reasonably good approximation is

```
[^[:ascii:][:print:]]
```

which matches characters that are either non-ASCII or non-printable.  The question stands open, of course, whether to be a printable ASCII code is enough for being acceptable as part of a file name...